# Converting years to years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: javascript, time, days, seconds

I have been working on a program, and one part of the program needs to be able to convert years to years, months, days, etc. I have worked on a couple of solutions, and I seem to have hit upon a way to do it, but it only works up on years and months, and for days onward it doesn't work.

I have tried to find the problem, but I simply have no idea where the problem could be. The code is exactly the same as for years and months, just with days and smaller units of time instead. This is the code:

```
time = time.toString();
if (time.includes(".")) {
  time = time.split(".");
  var yrs = time[0] + " yrs, ";
  time = time[1] * 12;
} else {
  time = time[0] + " yrs.";
}
if (time.includes(".")) {
  time = time.split(".");
  var mos = time[0] + " mos, ";
  time = time[1] * 30;
} else {
  time = yrs + time[0] + " mos.";
}
if (time.includes(".")) {
  time = time.split(".");
  var dys = time[0] + " dys, ";
  time = time[1] * 24;
} else {
  time = yrs + mos + time[0] + " dys.";
}
if (time.includes(".")) {
  time = time.split(".");
  var hrs = time[0] + " hrs, ";
  time = time[1] * 60;
} else {
  time = yrs + mos + dys + time[0] + " hrs.";
}
if (time.includes(".")) {
  time = time.split(".");
  var mins = time[0] + " mins, ";
  time = time[1] * 60;
} else {
  time = yrs + mos + dys + hrs + time[0] + " mins.";
}
if (time.includes(".")) {
  time = time.split(".");
  var secs = time[0] + " secs.";
  time = yrs + mos + dys + hrs + mins + secs;
}
```

I expected it to output, for example, with 2.24 years: '2 yrs, 2 mos, 26 days, 9 hrs, 26 mins.' Instead, after taking out the code that doesn't work, it outputs `'undefined0 yrs mos, '`.

Thanks in advance for helping out!

Edit: This is NOT using dates. I am just trying to convert units of years with decimals into years and months and days, etc. So please do not recommend things like moment.js that utilize dates.

Comment: Would strongly recommend utilizing moment.js or some other. Time is hard.

Comment: I highly recommend using the moment.js library for all datetime conversion stuff. https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Would use momentjs.com as well ;@

Comment: You can use [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/)

Comment: All those ifs that repeat?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to know the exact start date to be able to calculate this? What about leap years and differences in the lengths of individual months? I realize that 30-day months are used in some accounting or financial contexts, but still...